# Is there a way to set JVM arguments on Eclipse Indigo for an Android Project?

Tags: java, android, jvm-arguments, eclipse-indigo

I developed an application on Java that needs the following to run and be able to invoke a webservice throught HTTPS.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\directory\local.keystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\directory\local.keystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
-javaagent:C:\directory\fakehostverification.jar
```

Now I am developing a similar application for Android with Eclipse Indigo, but I can't find the way to use those arguments.
Where I can set those arguments on Eclipse Indigo for an Android Project?
Is this possible? If not, what can I do?

[image: Run Configuration for Android Project vs Java Project]

Answer (score 0):

**Right click** the **project**. Select **Run as** --> **Run Configurations**.

You can change the parameters passed to the JVM in the **Arguments tab** in the **VM Arguments box.**

Comment: I just see Android, Target and Common tabs for Android Projects. On the same Eclipse Indigo on Java Projects I can see the Arguments tab.